# Background image renders differently on server then on localhost

Tags: html, css, background-image, zurb-foundation

I have setup streched background on the homepage of https://picup.it through the class

```
<div class="bg-background">
```

Which is defined as below:

```
.bg-background {
    height: 100%; 
}

.bg-background:after{
    background: url({% static "images/picup-bg-01.jpg" %}) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.6;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
};
```

However, it looks slight different on localhost. In production (picup.it) background image is stretched to the screen size - you can observer that after scrolling down a div with panel is going out of the background image.

On localhost however, background image covers full div and goes below the scrolling - until the place where div ends.

Why? Same with Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: Are you using the same version of web server both local and on production?

Comment: How it is related? Locally I develop on Django, on production I add nginx layer.

Comment: Just trying to narrow down possibilities. If the code is the same, the image is the same, the browser is the same, the only thing left is differences in the server.

Answer (score 1):

add a background image to your body and fix that image

body
    {

```
    background: #fff url(/static/images/picup-bg-01.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

}
```

Comment: I don't want to have a background on full body. I want to have background only in that div which I wrote about.

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax instead

```
.bg-background {
    background:url({% static "images/picup-bg-01.jpg" %}) center no-repeat;
    height:565px; /* just pick a random height */
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-size:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It may also due to you didnt specify a height, thus it scaled differently.

---

second explanation, upon inspecting your html dom struture you did.

```
<body>
<div class='bg-background'>
   <!--- html content -->
</div>
</body>
```

should be this instead

```
<body>
<div class='bg-background'>
</div>
<div id='body-content'>
<!-- html content -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. same happens when I put background-size: 100% 100%; , and your changes didn't help :(

Comment: If that is the case the only explanation i have is either - your in a localhost environment, some additional css did not load / your body element or outer div wasnt define properly.

Comment: added a second explanation - ive implemented something similar a while back never had this issue, you can check and mimic what i did [on this site](http://tinyurl.com/nl5vep5)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any browser extension? It might be CSS code is being injected into the page.

---

**Second idea:**

You could try changing your code into:

```
background-image: url('images/picup-bg-01.jpg');
```

for one, and keep:

```
background-size: 100%;
content: "";
opacity: 0.6;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
```

**EDIT:**

If you use the `Tryit Editor` from the `w3schools` website, you'll see that your CSS code appears exactly as it does on your website (with the unstretched height), whereas using `background-image` in the same editor does provide you with the expected 100% height size.

**EDIT #2:**

Actually, it's not exactly what I said while writing EDIT #1. If I use your style code for the `body` of the page in the editor I get what you currently have on your website. If I use it in a `div`, however, it is properly scaled.

The code I provided seems to be working on both scenarios, though.

Comment: What do you see under the address https://picup.it ? I have checked with two browsers (as you see Chromium and Firefox) also in private modes without running plugins.

Comment: Well, the image is scaled to fit the screen width

Comment: If  you read the question please note that I want my picture to stretch to size of <div class="bg-background">, not the screen. Width is ok - concern is about the height.

Comment: Did you try `background-image: url('images/picup-bg-01.jpg');` with `background-size: 100%;`?

Comment: I would very much like to know whether that did the trick or if you found another solution/explanatation.