# how to set background image of a div with css?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010

this is what I am trying in visual studio:

```
    <div id="cont" style=" background-image:url(C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite5\Tulips.jpg); width:300px; height: 300px">
```

But the div doesn't show any image. I have also tried setting the url to only "Tulips.jpg". What is wrong with the code?

Comment: make sure your path is relative to the css file.

Comment: where is your page located? If it's in the root, setting the image to `Tulips.jpg` should work, otherwise you need to define the path.

Comment: Also, are you trying to view this in VS or a browser? That path to the image will not work in a browser if you're viewing it in a server environment.

Comment: I've answered something similar on this post [background image][1], take a look


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22353659/3385391

Comment: did any of the answers solve the issue..?

Answer (score 0):

if you try to put there a link to an online picture, it works fine. therefore i think its safe to assume that your website doesnt have access to the location of the pic on your computer.
either grant that folder read access to IUSR (iis default user ) or put the picture into your project's folder and use a relative path to it. drag the picture from the resources window into your html file and visual studio will generate the relative path for you.

Answer (score -1):

The HTML

```
<div class="your-css-class-name">
    blah blah blah
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.your-css-class-name{
   background:url('path/to/background_image.jpg');
}
```